# Как поменять размер шрифта в Windows консоли используя Python 3.5

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, консоль, шрифты

Можно ли поменять размер шрифта, и сам шрифт в консоли Python 3.5. Если да, то как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение для Windows.

Для изменения размера шрифта в cmd требуется доступ к windows api

Решение с [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/) (выбираете инсталлер под свою версию питона и разрядность ос)

```
import win32console
p = win32console.PyConsoleScreenBufferType(win32console.GetStdHandle( win32console.STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ))
# p = _
p.SetConsoleFont(1)
p.SetConsoleFont(2)
```

Параметр `SetConsoleFont` "не документирован MSDN".

[image: пример изменения шрифта в консоли]

Comment: Выдает ошибку c:\PyTake\test>test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyTake\test\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    p = _
NameError: name '_' is not defined

Comment: @EvleapsCorp. Можно ещё ctypes использовать, чтобы подобные функции вызвать. [Change console font in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3592673/4279)

Comment: Поправил код, так получается универсальнее

Comment: не получается, выдает ошибку, вот скрин. http://imgur.com/a/YOiOg

Comment: @jfs Спасибо большое, через ctypes работает, только код слишком большой получается. А так всё хорошо. но хотелось бы попробовать wein32console. Меньше кода и все понятно.

Comment: @EvleapsCorp. Уберите код в отдельный модуль и назовите его `your_package.win32console`. Так у вас код и работает и маленький (в месте вызова, только функция).

Comment: @jfs Да, не подумал об этом))Всё работает.

Comment: можно ещё попробовать [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26479960/4279) вызвать (на Vista и выше) как показано [по ссылке выше](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3592673/4279)

Answer (score -4):

На сколько я знаю нельзя,пользуйтесь средой разработки (Pycharm и тд.)там точно можно.Попробуйте поменять шрифт в настройках ОС.

Comment: Точнее поменять шрифт средствами Python

Comment: Сложно себе консоль в GUI среде представить, в которой нельзя шрифт поменять.

Comment: Нет,средствами Python это нельзя сделать.